# I'm having a weird issue with a Fortran code

Tags: arrays, fortran, gnu, gfortran, matrix-factorization

I am fairly new to Fortran programming so this might be an obvious issue, so bear with me.
Here is the code I am working with:

```
program A1H

! Householder transformation

implicit none
integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15,307) ! Double precision kind

real(kind=dp), dimension(6,3)::A
real(kind=dp), dimension(6,1)::b
integer, dimension(6,6)::Pglobal ! Global identity matrix
integer::i,j,g
g = size(A,1)
do j=1,g
   do i=1,g
       Pglobal(i,j) = (i/j)*(j/i)
   end do
end do
b(:,1) = [1237,1941,2417,711,1177,475]
A(1,:) = [1,0,0]
A(2,:) = [0,1,0]
A(3,:) = [0,0,1]
A(4,:) = [-1,1,0]
A(5,:) = [-1,0,1]
A(6,:) = [0,-1,1]
call mat_print('A',A)
call mat_print('b',b)
call mat_print('Pglobal',Pglobal)
call householder(A,b)

contains

subroutine householder(A,b)
real(kind=dp), intent(in)::A(:,:),b(:,:)
real(kind=dp)::alpha,gamma,beta
real(kind=dp), dimension(6,6)::H
real(kind=dp), dimension(6,3)::y,aa
real(kind=dp), dimension(6,1)::yy,v,dglobal,ek,bb
real(kind=dp), dimension(1,6)::d
integer::k,m,n,j
m = size(A,1)
n = size(A,2)
aa = A
bb = b
do k=1,n
   dglobal(:,k) = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
   alpha = -sign(aa(k,k),aa(k,k))*norm2(aa(k:m,k))
   ek(:,1) = Pglobal(:,k) 
   dglobal(k:m,k) = aa(k:m,k)
   v(:,k) = (dglobal(:,k)) - alpha*ek(:,1) 
   d(k,:) = v(:,k)
   beta = dot_product(d(k,:),v(:,k))
   if (beta==0) then
       continue
   end if
   H = Pglobal - (2/beta)*(matmul(reshape(v(:,k),(/m,1/)),reshape(d(k,:),(/1,m/)))) 
   y = matmul(H,aa)
   yy = matmul(H,bb)
   aa = y
   bb = yy
   call mat_print('aa',y)
   call mat_print('bb',yy)
end do

end subroutine

! Matrix print subroutine

subroutine mat_print(b,a)
    character(*), intent(in)::b
    class(*), intent(in)::a(:,:)
    integer::i
    print*,' '
    print*,b
    do i=1,size(a,1)
        select type (a)
        type is (real(kind=dp)) ; print'(100f9.4)',a(i,:)
        type is (integer) ; print'(100i9  )',a(i,:)
        end select
    end do
    print*,' '
 end subroutine

 end program
```

The issue I'm having is that when I change the variable `aa` to another name, I get the wrong result for the `y` variable; if I leave it as is, it is correct; however, leaving the `bb` variable as is, the `yy` result is incorrect, but if I change the `bb` variable to another other name, I get the correct result for `yy`, but then my answer for `y` changes! I'm very confused how this can happen as my experience from coding tells me that the answer should not change based on a simple variable name change, and if you look at the code, the `y` and `yy` variables are not even connected in the algorithm. This is not the only Fortran code I have run into this issue before on. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you change the name to? Without further analysing your issue, a procedure that is contained in the main program has access to all the main program's variables, **except** those that get hidden by declaring a variable of that name within the procedure. That's the first idea I have on why the variable name could matter.

Comment: Question, should `Pglobal` represent the unity-matrix, if so ... this is a fascinating way of doing it.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Due to integer division it will actually create an identity matrix with only `1` on the diagonal.

Comment: @chw21 Anything that I have not already declared a variable name to, either in the subroutines or not, so for example f,q, etc.

Comment: @kvantour yes it is the identity matrix

Comment: @kvantour:   D'ohhhh, missed that completely.

Comment: I cant reproduce your issue. I compiled and run your code both as is and changing all `aa` into `f` and I got the exact same results. Are you sure you are doing the renaming correctly?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues yes absolutely. I'm about fed up with Fortran at this point. I'm having so many issues that should not be happening...another example is I have a print *,"variable name" statement in another code and if I comment this line off I get NaN's all the way across the board as my answer, but if I leave the print statement in the code I get the correct answers. It flabbergasts me. I'm beginning to think it isn't a problem with the codes themselves but rather my compiler...any thoughts? Using gfortran

Comment: Which version of gfortran are you using? I'm doing my tests with `gfortran version 9.0.0 20181028 (experimental)`

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I am using GNU Fortran (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce your bug with `GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 8.2.0) 8.2.0`. There is indeed a bug in your program. You can find this bug by compiling with the option `-fbounds_check`. When you run it, you will find that several of your array access don't make sense. For example, you access `dglobal(:,k) = [0,0,0,0,0,0]`, but the second dimension of `dglobal` is only 1. Use this flag to help fix your code, and I'm sure this bug will disappear.

For anyone who wants to dig deep into why this bug's appearance depends on the variable name, I was able to reproduce it with the array name `test_array`, but not with other shorter names. I was also able to get the correct answer using the `test_array` name if I set `-fmax-stack-var-size=100`, and other values appeared with different sizes. My guess is that gfortran puts these arrays on the stack, and the order is based on the name. Certain names put it in a "safe" location, so that the values are not overwritten by the buffer overflow.

Comment: Thanks @KobeGote I'll fix this issue and any other incorrect array accesses and give you an update

Comment: Update: @KobeGote referencing elements in the arrays that did not exist was the main problem and also fixed the variable name change problem. I suppose your response to how the variable name change affected the answers is correct, but I still find it rather intriguing. Thanks for everyone's help!